# calculations with rasters that are a bit different in dimensions and resolution

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster

I would like to multiply the two rasters (in R) but they do not match exactly. What are my options to be able to multiply the rasters?

```
> veg_g
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2416, 2807, 6781712  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 109067.2, 109769, 533016.5, 533620.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)

> garden_5mplus
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2416, 2804, 6774464  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.2502728, 0.2500402  (x, y)
extent     : 109067.3, 109769.1, 533016.4, 533620.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : BBOXrs_rAHN3_05m_DSM 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert them to the same resolution using `resample()`:

```
require("raster")
garden_5mplus <- resample(garden_5mplus, veg_g)
```

There is also a `resample()` function in `raster`'s successor package `terra`.

Comment: Is it possible to multiple them by keeping their original resolution or I am forced to resample them?

Comment: If they have different resolutions, a cell in one grid overlaps with multiple cells in the other grid. If you want to multiply each cell from the grid one with one cell from grid two, you need to resample them. Writing a function to multiply a cell in grid one with all intersecting cells in grid two would also be possible.